# Get stored WiFi networks with a cmd oneliner

Tags: windows, cmd

I would like to run this as a 1 line command (not from a batch), but however I try, I cannot succeed:

```html
(for /f  "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profiles ^| findstr "Profile"') do (
    set str=%%a
    set str=!str:~1!
    echo !str!
)) >> wifi_networks.txt
```

This is what I tried:

```html
(for /f  "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profiles ^| findstr "Profile"') do (set str=%%a & set str=!str:~1! & echo !str!)) >> wifi_networks.txt
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a batch file, you double up the **`%`**'s, as you aren't they should be returned to single again.

Try this, *(untested)*:

```dos
(For /F "Tokens=2Delims=:" %A In ('NetSh WLAN Show Profiles^|Find "Profile"') Do @For /F "Tokens=*Delims= " %B In ("%A") Do @Echo %B)>>"wifi_networks.txt"
```

If `wifi_networks.txt` doesn't already exist you can change **`>>`** to **`>`**.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!